# Why Eclipse has two projects with different java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects on one Eclipse.
I haven't set "java.library.path" steps below:

1. Run Configurations
2. Arguments
3. VM arguments
4. Type "java.library.path [path]" to set path for specific project

However, when I use below code to print it, the output is different.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

The output are like below：
Project 1：

```
C:\Users\gearon\workspace\xxx\lib\win32;C:\Users\gearon\workspace\xxx\lib\x86
```

Project 2:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

So why it's different?

Comment: Did you choose the same runtime JRE in both run configurations (in the _JRE_ tab)?

Comment: @howlger No, they used same JRE

Answer (score 0):

2 projects uses different JRE

1. Uses some embedded JRE that would probably ship with application (like eg. JIRA)
2. Uses system java 1.7